# How to get all instances from database?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am forced to make "simple" project. The teacher wants mongoDb and node js. I want to get all cars from my db, but find() doesn't work.
My code Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CarSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    mark:{
        type: String,
        required: true,},
    model:{
        type: String,
        required: true,},
    price:{
        type: Number,
        required: true,},
    available: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,},
    pic_1:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    pic_2:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    }


})

const Car = mongoose.model('Car', CarSchema)
module.exports = Car
```

Route:

```
router.get('/getAll', (req, res) =>{
    const cr=Car.find({});
    console.log(cr);
    res.render('main', {user: req.user, cars:cr} );

});
```

Console.log shows everytthing but not list of the cars ;) More strictly: it shows structure of app and directors. How to fix it? And how to do it without =>{} - it's very illegible,long and my eyes bleeding. I just want to take all cars from db, assign them to the var and then render view with that cars.

There are a lot of questions, but no one answer solved my issue!
Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Car.find() is an asynchronous operation.

*Solution 1: Using async/await*

```
router.get('/getAll', async (req, res) =>{
    const cr = await Car.find({});
    console.log(cr);
    res.render('main', {user: req.user, cars:cr} );

});
```

*Solution 2: Using callback function*

```
router.get('/getAll', (req, res) =>{
    Car.find({}, (error, cars) => {
        console.log(cars);
        res.render('main', {user: req.user, cars: cars} );
    });
});
```

If you don't want to use the arrow functions then change as shown below

```
() => {}    >    function() {}
```

Changes to your code

```
router.get('/getAll', async function(req, res) {
    const cr = await Car.find({});
    console.log(cr);
    res.render('main', {user: req.user, cars:cr} );
});
```

Reference:

[Async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)

[Making asynchronous programming easier with async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await)

[Mongoose - Model.find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

[Arrow functions](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions-basics)